# what is difference between model created with createBean and this.model present in js file?

Tags: backbone.js, sugarcrm

I've been doing experiments from 2days to figure out the difference. 
So I've put

```
console.log (self.model);
```

in /custom/modules/Emails/clients/base/views/preview/preview.js and Yes I'm in an async operation there thats why I'm using self;
And I did this.

```
var accountsBean = app.data.createBean('Emails', {id:self.model.get('id)')});
```

But I've found there is a lot of difference between them.
self.model have to_collection,from_collection filled with data whereas these fields are empty in accountsBean but to_addrs_names,from_addr_name are filled and those are not present in self.model

Is there anything I'm missing related to core functionality or anything related to backbone?

I'm trying to launch Email Drawer like this.

```
                var accountsBean = app.data.createBean('Emails', {id: self.model.get('id)')});
                accountsBean.fetch({
                    view: "compose-email",
                    success: function (col,data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var prefill = app.data.createBean('Emails');
                        prefill.copy(data);
                        app.drawer.open({
                            layout: 'compose-email',
                            context: {
                                create: true,
                                model: prefill,
                                module: 'Emails',
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
```

Even if I use

```
var prefill = app.data.createBean('Emails'); prefill.copy(data);
```

I'm getting an error

```
FATAL[2018-3-9 16:40:8]: Uncaught TypeError: e.has is not a function
```

If I just pass data in context

```
app.drawer.open({
          layout: 'compose-email',
          context: {
          create: true,
          model: data,
          module: 'Emails',
          }
})
```

then I',m getting this error.

```
FATAL[2018-3-9 17:6:19]: Uncaught TypeError: this.model.on is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used `accountsBean.fetch({success:console.log})` after?

It's always a good idea to specify `fields` (array of field names) or `view` (name of view) in the fetch options, to let the server know what fields you need - as not all fields will be transmitted by default (to save bandwidth and increase performance).

If you don't specify any of those options the server will just load some default which may not contain all the fields.

e.g. Try

```
accountsBean.fetch({
    view: "preview",
    success: console.log
})
```

This should result in a model containing fields specified in the preview viewdefs.

If you just want to fetch certain fields, you could use e.g.

```
accountsBean.fetch({
    fields: ["from_collection", "to_collection"],
    success: console.log
})
```

Comment: Thanks, where can I find this ?is it in the documentation? This worked, even the data is coming the way I exactly wanted. But my further step was use this model as prefill data for compose-email drawer. So I'm passing it in app.drawer.open({layout:'compose-emai',context:{create:true,model:data,module:'Emails'} }). But I'm getting an error while doing that. Any hint or help is appreciated and I'm new to Sugarcrm and it is very hard to find answers.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to build my own Reply button, so I wanted to prefill data for the reply but I'm still having trouble with fields like to_collection. I've used reply-action.js and forward-action.js functions to format the data properly for the reply.(I've copied them because I didn't found any way to use them or how to include them). Previously the data was getting prefilled correctly but there was an issue with to_collection field now the data is in perfect format but now the model which I've used in success callback is giving error while launching the drawer.

Comment: Hm, I couldn't really find any documentation regarding bean fetching in JavaScript/sidecar... (but they are surely some mentions about it in the sugarcrm community or the sugarcrm dev blog).

Can you be more specific about the error you're getting when launching the drawer? Also: Maybe edit your question to include the code you're using now.

Comment: Well, I've already posted many questions on sugar community but no one gives a reply. Maybe what I'm asking is pretty dumb things but there is literally less support and answers for sugar if I'm not wrong. I just want custom reply button which works exactly like normal reply but even that's hard to figure out smh.

Comment: `success: function (col,data) {` -- um, aren't you mixing up the arguments there? Should be `(data, req)`? You're passing the request instead of the model as prefill.

Comment: And well, couldn't you just create a second button of the same field type? Also maybe extending the View could do the trick - depending on what exactly do you want to do. Just another reply button at a different location? Or is there anything that should be different to the original reply button's functionality for that other button? Or do you just want to change behavior of the original button?
Oh right. Also Email module changed alot in recent months, what version are you on?

Comment: Im using 7.11 Professiona version. You can check here what I really want to build and what I've build so far https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/32477-tinymce-in-preview-panel-and-email-functionality. Actually I wanted tinyMCE in preview but I found that hard so for now as workaroud I just want email drawer to be opened as reply action.

Comment: And for success parameters, I checked that in console the first one col is giving me collection and second one i.e data is giving me object which holds data.

Comment: And can you elaborate more about creating second button of the same field type? Because I've searched that but I couldn't find anything related to it. Because there is already reply-action field but I've no idea how to use that in preview panel and do things what I want.

Comment: Sorry, You were right about success parameters but I don't know it was giving me list or records with next offset like something. Is that asycn issue? Well compose drawer is now getting populated but only "to" field is not getting populated and I already have log so now that model is showing to_collection is empty. I've used emailOptionTo function from reply-action.js to convert from_collection to to_collection

Comment: Hrm. I checked your post on community forums.
As this is in preview view rather than record view, things are a bit trickier I guess. Just copying the button from record.php to preview.php won't do the trick, because prefill seems to silently break due to changed context and/or view. Also adding `"type" => "htmleditable_tinymce"` to `description_html` field in `preview.php` doesn't seem to do anything in preview, so that will need some tinkering as well...

I'm afraid I can't be much of help (no time atm either), but I'll try to check back later and see if you could figure it out :) GL!

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate that and Yes it is hell tricky that's why for a workaround I'm just trying to launch email drawer via that button. Well, I got success now but the thing remaining is the pre-populated field to is saying invalid. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh and with regards to `data` argument of `success` callback: I'd expect it to contain a model or a collection respective to what object type .fetch() is called on. If you call .fetch() on the *collection* of Emails, data will contain a collection of the fetched emails. The models can then be found in data.models. However, be aware that by default only up to 20 models are fetched. Specify e.g. `limit: 100` in the fetch options if you want to fetch a different max amount (default server hard cap is 1000 I think). `next_offset` and such allows you to page through all records.

Answer (score 0):

HI If you want to just open a Module in Drawer Check this code .

```
({
  extendsFrom: 'SubpanelListView',
  initialize: function(options){
     this._super('initialize', [options]);
     this.context.on('list:drawereditrow:fire',this.drawerEditClicked, this);
  },
  drawerEditClicked: function(model){
    app.drawer.open({
       layout:'create-actions',
       context:{
         create: true,
         model: model,
         module:'oppp_Opportunity_Products',
       }
    });
  },
   _dispose: function() {
     this._super('_dispose');
   },
});
```

For More Info check this [Link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/User_Interface/Drawers/)